# Center inline block images

Tags: html, css, centering

I need some help centering some images

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbs" class="navigation">
<ul class="thumbs noscript">
<li>
    <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015_s.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015_s.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015_s.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<br>
<li>
    <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015_s.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015_s.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
ul.thumbs {
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

ul.thumbs li {
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left;*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
    list-style: none;
}

a.thumb {
    padding: 2px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.thumbs li.selected a.thumb {
    background: #DAA12F;
}

a.thumb:focus {
    outline: none;
}

ul.thumbs img {
    border: none;
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

I need the images be centered together so that they remained lined up. Ive tried using:

```
ul.thumbs {
    text-align:center;
}
```

but since there are a different number of images on each row, they move out of alignment

Thanks for the help, this is driving me crazy

**EDIT:** I thought I found a solution using this as a guide: http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm but if the images go over more than row, they no longer center. Originally I put a br tag to break up the rows and that fixes the problem, but a JS library Im using doesnt play nice with br tags between list items. Any suggestions (you can see the issue here http://jsfiddle.net/HvZva/26/)

Comment: Centered like all in a straight line down? Or in the center of the page but the left of both rows flush? Can you show a diagram of how you want them lined up?

Comment: Is this the sort of thing your after?
http://jsfiddle.net/HvZva/12/

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, your solutions are on the right track, but I should have been more explicit, the solution cant be hard coded as I may have any number of images which need to be aligned. Here is an http://i.imgur.com/TCnWF.png As you can see in both examples, the images as a group are centered, but if there is more than 1 row they continue to line up

Comment: Found the solution using this as a guide: http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm my solution available here: http://jsfiddle.net/HvZva/23/

Comment: Solution doesnt quite work. See edit above

Answer (score 1):

There is two solutions to this, one is if you want your images to be centered and the another is if your images should be aligned left, but centered on the page.

**Center block, left align images**
To do this you need to add the following to your css (or see: http://jsfiddle.net/HvZva/20/)

```
ul.thumbs{
margin:0 auto;
width:416px;
}
```

what I do is basicly to tell the browser that this un ordered list should have an equal margin to both sides. But since this object has an width of 100% as standard, we need to specifiy that aswell, and in this case it is 416px.

**Center align images**

If this is static content, one easy way to do this is to add a div with the class of center that wraps each line, and then adding "text-align:center;" to those divs, that will do the trick.

note: there is one new way to center the block, but aligning the images to the left. but that involves the box flex model and css 3, and it has not yet been implemented by browsers yet

Comment: Thats still not quite what I need. As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/HvZva/22/, since the width is fixed at 416px, if there is only 1 image, it is not centered on the page

Comment: You need to use the total width of all the elements - needs to be a minimum. If you want all images to be centered then use the second code, align:center.

The width is both the width of the element, padding, margin and some more spacing since you have list items and they are inline-blocks. so you need to test some diffrent widths if you want to have only three images or two.

Comment: The problem is I dont know how many images I will have as they are created dynamically, hence I cant hard code the width in. I almost found a solution (see edit in original post) however, it doesnt quite work when there are too many images and a new row is required

Answer (score 0):

Applying `text-align: center;` to .thumbs.noscript ul fixes it in the jsfiddle

Comment: well it looks like everybody interpreted your question differently - you should have your answer between these three

Answer (score 0):

You can give the parent element a width and apply `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/HvZva/13/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.thumbs {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HvZva/11/

Answer (score -1):

I may have mis interpreded your issue but is it something like this you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/HvZva/12/